# Возможно ли вызывать функцию из C# в JS

Tags: javascript, c#, chromium

Возможно ли зарегистрировать функцию в C#, и передать её в Chromium.
Допустим, есть функция на C# , которая будет выглядеть так:

```
void ShowMessage(string text){
    MessageBox.Show(text);
}
```

А потом вызвать эту функцию из JS:

```
<script>ShowMessage("Test");</script>
```

Возможно ли реализовать такое?

Comment: Зависит от того, где такая фишка нужна

Comment: А Chromium умеет исполнять C#-код?

Comment: Опишите более детально как организовано приложение в котором вы используете Chromium, от этого зависит реализация.

Comment: Если JS подключена через стандартную ActiveX либу, можно добавить метод на экспорт в js `ScriptControl.AddObject("ShowMessage",обьект_метода)` обьект_метода - должен быть COM-совместимым.

Comment: Как именно вы встраиваете Chromium в C# приложение? Возможно, вы используете какую-то библиотеку? Какую?

Comment: В компоненте `WebBrowser` (обёртка IE) это можно сделать. Либо с помощью `AttachEventHandler`, либо навешивая фукнцию C# на событие `Click` кнопки в браузере. А Хромиум, похоже, так не умеет.

Comment: Chromium использую из CefSharp.

Answer (score 0):

Делал подобную вещь для Selenium + `executeScriptAsync` и свой код на стороне клиента. Насколько я знаю, CefSharp тоже позволяет вызвать `executeScriptAsync`. Идея в том, что C# код вызывает метод в JS, который не возвращает управление назад до тех пор, пока не нужно будет вызвать что-то из C#. То есть по сути это такой обратный вызов наоборот. Мы вызываем JS из C#, при этом C# код по сути ждёт, пока JS что-то захочет получить или сделать. И можно следующим вызовом передать результат.

Упрощенный пример на JS для однократного вызова. C# код устанавливает _requestReadyCallback в JS, который его потом вызывает и этот вызов "отпускает" ожидание C# кода на ExecuteAsyncScript, потом выполняется C# код и отдает ответ путем вызова другой функции в JS:

```
var _requestReadyCallback;
function setSeleniumCallback(seleniumCallback) {
    _requestReadyCallback = seleniumCallback;
}

function replyFromSelenium(data) {
    console.log('Got reply from Selenium ' + data);
}

window.setTimeout(() => { _requestReadyCallback("getDate"); }, 2000);
```

C#

```
var dataFromJs = browser.ExecuteAsyncScript("setSeleniumCallback(arguments[0]);");
Console.WriteLine($"Received '{dataFromJs}' at {DateTime.Now}");
browser.ExecuteScript("replyFromSelenium(arguments[0])", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

В production-коде я использую очередь Promise-ов на стороне JS и do {...} while цикл в C# обработки запросов. В результате JS не блокирован на получение ответа от C# и C# код не делает polling, ожидая запроса ровно столько, сколько нужно.

Альтернативным вариантом будет поднять локальный http сервер на C# и обращаться к нему из Javascript